# Setting up sshkey for git bash on windows 10 VM

Tags: bitbucket, virtual-machine, git-bash, ssh-keygen

OS: Ubuntu with windows 10 VM

Goal: Setup git bash on the Windows 10 VM with an ssh key to use with private Bitbucket.

Overview: 
Generating an SSH key into a non-default location to work with git bash did not work. An attempted solution was to create default location and move the key to that location to test. I do not know enough about how the default location is generated, or how git bash searches for the sshkey to compare with bitbucket. I suspect network drives/IT may be impacting the issue but do not know the correct questions to ask. The steps and details are below. Yes the ssh key was added to bitbucket account.

When generating the ssh key the suggestion location is /home/username/.ssh... I am not sure where this suggested path comes from. I have set several computers up with git bash/ssh keys and this suggested path varies. **How does this suggested path get set?** and **How is the ssh key Search Path set?**

```
ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/plane/.ssh/id_rsa): /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa
```

```
~ pwd = c/Users/username
```

**/** does exist, but **home** does not exist

```
$ ls -l /
total 3076
drwxr-xr-x  1 username 1061577       0 Feb  3 15:57 bin/
drwxr-xr-x  1 username 1061577       0 Feb  3 15:57 cmd/
drwxr-xr-x  1 username 1061577       0 Feb  3 15:57 dev/
drwxr-xr-x  1 username 1061577       0 Feb  3 15:57 etc/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 username 1061577  152112 Jan 13 20:31 git-bash.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 username 1061577  151600 Jan 13 20:31 git-cmd.exe*
-rw-r--r--  1 username 1061577   18765 Dec 10 18:25 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-xr-x  1 username 1061577       0 Feb  3 15:56 mingw64/
dr-xr-xr-x 13 username 1061577       0 Feb  3 17:57 proc/
-rw-r--r--  1 username 1061577  160771 Jan 13 21:08 ReleaseNotes.html
drwxr-xr-x  1 username 1061577       0 Feb  3 17:02 tmp/
-rw-r--r--  1 username 1061577 1161914 Feb  3 15:57 unins000.dat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 username 1061577 1299888 Feb  3 15:51 unins000.exe*
-rw-r--r--  1 username 1061577   22795 Feb  3 15:57 unins000.msg
drwxr-xr-x  1 username 1061577       0 Feb  3 15:57 usr/
```

Permissions denied

```
mkdir -p /home/username
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home’: Permission denied
```

Git Clone:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@git.example.com/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
Could not create directory '/home/username/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'example' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts).
example: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Edit:

I have attempted the following as well.

In an effort to indicate where .ssh actually is, and where I want it to be.
**/c/Users/plane/.ssh**

```
git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

1) Could not create **'/home/plane/.ssh'**

2) Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts **(/home/plane/.ssh/known_hosts)**.

3) **Load key "/c/Users/plane/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"**: invalid format

```
git clone ssh://git@git.project
Cloning into 'project'...
Could not create directory '/home/plane/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/plane/.ssh/known_hosts).
Load key "/c/Users/plane/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": invalid format
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Thank you,

Comment: This is really old / late, but you should use the private key for authentication (add the pub key to your Github user settings).

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

- a regular CMD (in your Windows 10 VM) with a simplified path

  ```
  set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
  set GH=C:\path\to\git
  set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
  ```
- a key generated in the default %USERPROFILE%.ssh folder

  ```
  ssh-keygen -P "" -t rsa -m PEM
  ```
- register the `id_rsa.pub` content to [your BitBucket profile](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html#SetupanSSHkey-Step5.AddthepublickeytoyourBitbucketsettings)

---

> The `known_hosts` is still referenced at the default location `/home/username/.ssh`.
>   How do I change this default location?

This is managed by the `$HOME/%HOME%` environment variable.
SSH will look for `known_hosts` in `$HOME/.ssh`

Comment: I do not see the connection between the PATH and where the default ssh-keygen dir comes from. env shows the HOME and USERPROFILE, I can not find reference to /home/username.
 
env
HOME=/c/Users/plane
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\plane

Comment: @plane Are you using Git in a Windows 10 (VM) session? If so, the PATH is there to make sure there is no side-effect with any other program. It is just for testing.

Comment: I am able to generate an sshkey and add it to bitbucket, the specific problem I am having is with where git/gitbash thinks the ssh key is by default. 

I tried to modified the ssh location with:
```
 git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

The known_hosts is still referenced at the default location **/home/username/.ssh**. **How do I change this default location?**

Comment: @plane Are you using Git in a Windows 10 (VM) session?

Comment: I am using git for windows on a Windows 10 VM. Host OS Ubuntu, Guest OS Windows 10.

Comment: @plane OK. In your Windows VM session, in a regular CMD, do you have a `HOME` environment variable defined? (`set HOME`)

Comment: I am confused that SSH will look for known_hosts in $HOME/.ssh as I am seeing a varying result. 

**HOME=/c/Users/plane**

but it appears **/home/username/.ssh** is the search directory 

**/** is a dir that exists, **/home** does not exist

I have modified the original post detailing this information

Comment: C:\Users\plane>set HOME
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\plane

Comment: @plane Exactly, no HOME. type `set HOME=%USERPROFILE%`, then, from the same CMD, launch git bash. Check if the issue persists.

Comment: in gitbash env returens **HOME=/c/Users/plane**  and **USERPROFILE=C:\Users\plane** **Is env in gitbash returning different environmental variables than Windows? **How can gitbash show the env var is set to something?**

Comment: @plane Yes, that is expected: `/c/Users/plane` and `C:\Users\plane` are the same path. Now, ssh, run from git bash, will find your `known_hosts` file.

Comment: My apologies for the need to spell it out to fully understand. I understand that /c/ and C: are the same path. My understanding falls short that the **env** command tells me these paths are what I expect they should be, but Windows **set HOME** is telling us it is not set? and how this impacts the desired ssh path. As it seems redundant to me to **set HOME** to the path that *env* is already telling me it is

Comment: @plane yes, I always set it on Windows first, to be sure git bash will reuse the same path.

Comment: Do you have a reference for "SSH will look for known_hosts in $HOME/.ssh"

Comment: @plane https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh: "ssh automatically maintains and checks a database containing identification for all hosts it has ever been used with. Host keys are stored in ~/.ssh/known_hosts in the user's home directory."